# How to do summation of a function over a given range with range values inside the function

Tags: r, function, time-series

I have the following formula where b is a fixed value (upper limit of the summation):

[image: \sum_{a=3}^{b=5}(a/b)cov{(k(t),k(t-a))}]

K(t) is a value at t from given series k and k(t-a) is a value at lag a:

```
k<- rnorm(100, 1, .25)
```

My attempt:

```
(3/5)*cov(k,lag(k,k=3)) + (4/5)*cov(k,lag(k,k=4)) + (5/5)*cov(k,lag(k,k=5))
```

> Answer: 0.08400983

I need to evaluate the summation over various values up to 20. To illustrate:

```
b= 5:(3/5)*cov(k,lag(k,k=3)) + (4/5)*cov(k,lag(k,k=4)) + (5/5)*cov(k,lag(k,k=5))
b = 6: (3/6)*cov(k,lag(k,k=3)) + (4/6)*cov(k,lag(k,k=4)) + (5/6)*cov(k,lag(k,k=5)) +(6/6)*cov(k,lag(k,k=6))
b = 7: (3/7)*cov(k,lag(k,k=3)) + (4/7)*cov(k,lag(k,k=4)) + (5/7)*cov(k,lag(k,k=5)) +(6/7)*cov(k,lag(k,k=6)) + (7/7)*cov(k,lag(k,k=7))
```

I am confused how to sum this over the given interval. Kindly help me develop this function in R. Thanks

Comment: please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .. Show us what you did before asking for help.

Comment: You could at least explain this formula.. Because even from a mathematical background it is not clear.. sum for a =3 until b = 5 ?? There should be more information

Comment: @timat kindly review my question and let me know is it clear now?

Comment: Yes it is better but I'm not sure of the interpretation of the math formula (If b = 5 all the time, what is the point to have it under the symbol of the sum ?) Also, this formula is a fonction of (t) so your attempt should depend of t also..  What is this formula exactly? where does it come from?

Comment: Timat is explaining an issue to you. Your formula with "sum from a = 3 to b = 5" doesn't make sense. You need to clarify the values of a and b that you want to sum over. Your code attempt makes it looks like you want "from a = 3 to a = 5" with b always equal to 5, but you haven't confirmed in words if this is correct.

Comment: @Gregor Yes this is correct I want to sum over 3 to 5. Kindly review my question. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Kindly review my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
foo = function(k, start = 3, stop = 5) {
    result = 0
    for (i in start:stop) {
        result = result + i / stop * cov(k, stats::lag(k, k = i))
    }
    return(result)
}
```

Test that it works:

```
k = rnorm(100)
foo(k)
```

Now iterate over different values of `stop`. I use `sapply` instead of a `for` loop here because it's a little more R-like.

```
stops = 5:20
res = cbind(stops, sapply(stops, function(b) foo(k, start = 3, stop = b)))
res
#       stops         
#  [1,]     5 2.240816
#  [2,]     6 2.801020
#  [3,]     7 3.334547
#  [4,]     8 3.851402
#  [5,]     9 4.357142
#  [6,]    10 4.855101
#  [7,]    11 5.347401
#  [8,]    12 5.835458
#  [9,]    13 6.320249
# [10,]    14 6.802476
# [11,]    15 7.282651
# [12,]    16 7.761159
# [13,]    17 8.238293
# [14,]    18 8.714283
# [15,]    19 9.189310
# [16,]    20 9.663518
```